# Predual of $W^{1,\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I understand the meaning of $u_n$ converges to $u$ weak star (it means that $u_n\in E^*$ and $(u_n,x)_{E^*,E} \to (u,x)_{E^*,E}$ for all $x\in E$) but I've some trouble for identifying a space $E$ such that $E^* = W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). I know that we can identify $L^\infty(\Omega)$ to $L^1(\Omega)^*$ but what happens for $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ ?

It seems that we can identify the predual of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ as $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ as Terence Tao says [here](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/harmonicanalysis/conversations/topics/5) but where can I find a reference of this fact?

Comment: I haven't checked but $W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$ seems like a good bet...

Comment: @NateEldredge Can you explain a little more why it seems like a good bet?

Answer (score 2):

You may view $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ as a subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)^{n+1}$ (via $u \mapsto (u,\nabla u$), which can be identified with the dual of $L^1(\Omega)^{n+1}$.

Thus, for any bounded sequence $u_n$, there is a subsequence (without relabeling),
such that $u_n \stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup} u$ and $\partial_i u_n \stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup} v_i$ in $L^1(\Omega)^*$.
For any $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega) \subset L^1(\Omega)$ you have
\begin{equation*}
 \int_\Omega u_n \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x
 =
 -\int_\Omega \partial_i u_n \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
by definition of the weak derivative.
Passing to the limit $n \to \infty$ yields
\begin{equation*}
 \int_\Omega u \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x
 =
 -\int_\Omega v_i \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $u \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and $\partial_i u = v_i$.

Comment: Nice point but since $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is only a subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)^{n+1}$, all you can say for now is that the dual of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ contains $L^1(\Omega)^{n+1}$, right?

Comment: And we have that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is contained in the dual of $L^1(\Omega)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

This an old question, but I found the existing answer to be unsatisfactory since it doesn't give a proper description of the predual. Since this is not easy to find in the literature, I hope posting a detailed answer will be of value.

In practice, one often wants to understand duality through a suitable extension of the distributional pairing
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_{\Omega} f(x) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
In particular, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096093/sobolev-spaces-with-negative-exponent/4099664#4099664) regarding the identification $W^{-1,p^{\prime}}(\Omega) \simeq W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)^{\ast}.$ However, the endpoint $p=\infty$ case requires a slightly different formulation.

---

**Claim**: The pre-dual of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is given by the space of distributions
$$ W^{-1,1}(\Omega) =  \left\{ f_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{x_i}f_i \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega): f_0, f_1, \dots, f_n \in L^1(\Omega) \right\},$$
equipped with the norm
$$ \lVert T \rVert_{W^{-1,1}(\Omega)} = \inf\left\{\lVert f_0 \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} + \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert f_i \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} : \ T = f_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{x_i}f_i\right\},$$
where the isomorphism is defined via the pairing
$$ \langle g , T \rangle = \int_{\Omega} g(x) f_0(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\Omega}\partial_{x_i}g(x) f_i(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
One can show this as follows:

1. If $f_0, \cdots, f_n \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$, then the pairing is well-defined, linear, and bounded. In this case, one can integrate by parts and understand this as the standard distributional pairing with $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) \subset \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$.
2. By approximation, this extends to a well-defined and bounded linear functional on $W^{-1,1}(\Omega)$.
3. Conversely in $\Phi \in W^{-1,1}(\Omega)^{\ast}$, using $L^1(\Omega;\mathbb R^{n+1})^{\ast} \simeq L^{\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb R^{n+1})$ we get $(g_0,g_1,\dots,g_n) \in L^{\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb R^{n+1})$ such that
   $$ \langle \Phi, f_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_{x_i}f_i \rangle = \int_{\Omega} g_0 f_0 + g_1 f_1 + \cdots + g_n f_n \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
4. By considering $T = \partial_{x_i}f_0$ for $f_0 \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$, one can show that $\partial_{x_i} g_0 = -g_i$, so $\Phi$ is represented by $g_0 \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Hence this pairing is exact, which proves that $W^{-1,1}(\Omega)^{\ast} \simeq W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

---

Two remarks:

- Implicit in the pairing is that we think of elements of $W^{-1,1}(\Omega)$ to vanish on the boundary, which is encoded in the fact that $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{-1,1}(\Omega)$. This may seem confusing when compared to the case $1 \leq p<\infty$, where we consider $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and impose the more regular side to vanish on the boundary.
- If $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is sufficiently regular, we have the isomorphism $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Lip}(\Omega)$, and the latter space has an abstract predual description as the Arens-Eells space (see for instance *Lipschitz Algebras* by Nik Weaver). This makes sense more generally if $\Omega$ is replaced by a metric space $(X,d)$, however I do not believe this gives a useful description in terms of the duality pairing.