Density of which function space for a negative Sobolev space?
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (let us assume it has smooth boundary). We know that the Sobolev space $H_{-s}(\Omega)$ for a negative index $-s < 0$ can be defined in terms of duality i.e.
$$
f \in H_{-s}(\Omega) \iff \|f\|_{-s,\Omega} := \sup_{g \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega), \|g\|_{s,\Omega}=1} |\langle f,g\rangle| < \infty.
$$
Suppose now I want to define a different negative Sobolev space in the following way:
$$
f \in H_{-s}^*(\Omega) \iff \|f\|^*_{-s,\Omega} := \sup_{g \in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega}), \|g\|_{s,\Omega}=1} |\langle f,g\rangle| < \infty.
$$
Then can we say that $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ functions on $\Omega$ are dense in both $(H_{-s}(\Omega), \|.\|_{-s,\Omega})$ and $(H_{-s}^*(\Omega), \|.\|^*_{-s,\Omega})$ ? Any reference or proof will be highly appreciated.
I think I know that for non-negative Sobolev indices $s \geq 0$, $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ functions are dense (in fact this may be a definition of Sobolev spaces of positive indices right ?) in both $H_{s}(\Omega) \equiv H_{s}^*(\Omega)$ (the norms are same then).
 
A related link can be found here.

Good question. The following question might also help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096093/sobolev-spaces-with-negative-exponent
